# Help me correct this proof (Metric Space Topology)

Tags: analysis

Question: Let $X$ be a topological space. Prove if each point in $X$ is open, then each point in $X$  is closed.

Proof:

Suppose $\{x\}$ is open for $∀ x∈X$. Pick some arbitrary $x=x_1$. Clearly, $x_1$ is open so its complement $A = X\setminus\{x1\}$ is closed. Therefore, $A$ is a closed topological space consisting of $∀ x∈X$ closed provided $x=x_1$. In other words, we have shown that $∀ x∈X$ closed with the exception of $x= x_1$. In order to complete the proof, we repeat the above procedure by picking some arbitrary $x=x_2$ in order to show that $x_1$ is also closed, hence $x$ is closed for $∀ x∈X$.

---

Looking at what I wrote again, I know that the proof is wrong and that I am fudging it. Could someone give me a heads up about how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\in X$. Since every point of $X$ is open, the set $$U=\bigcup_{\substack{x\in X\\ x\neq p}}\{x\}$$ is open in $X$. But $U=X\setminus\{p\}$ so $\{p\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

Given: for all $x\in X$, it is known that $\{x\}$ is open.

To show: for all $x\in X$, the set $\{x\}$ is closed.

Proof: Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary point. To show that $\{x\}$ is closed, we need to show (by definition!) that $X-\{x\}$ is open.

Now, do you know that the union of any collection of open sets is open? so if $S\subseteq X$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, and since $X=\bigcup _{x\in X}\{x\}$, can you conclude that $S$ is open? Can you now conclude that $X-\{x\}$ is open?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand now. I do know that union of open is open. Only thing is that because I immediately when to X∖{x} is closed, and X is not stated as finite, I struggled because I didn't know if I could use finite union of closed is closed.